# Issue copying config.txt from host server to docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

So google has failed me so I'm hoping you good folks might be able to shed some light.

I'm trying to use a Docker to create a custom Jenkins Dockerfile with configs set up to have a 'pre-baked' Jenkins setup we can use across different projects.

Whenever I try the COPY command to copy the config.xml into the /var/jenkins_home/jobs folder it simply just doesn't do it. It doesn't show an error, it just isn't there when I log into the container or when I check the volume store on my host server (same location /var/jenkins_home/jobs).

My guess is that this is something to do with WORKDIR from the jenkins image but I'm no expert in docker. I'm able to add the config.xml to my volume on the host server and it works fine but I was wanting an image that was ready to go.

I've pasted my Dockerfile below, I'm running this from a directory located at /opt/jenkins_config:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

## Change to root user
USER root

## Name the jobs
ARG job_name_1=Generate-Key
ARG job_name_2=Generate-Stack

## Create the job workspaces
RUN mkdir -p "$JENKINS_HOME"/workspace/${job_name_1}
RUN mkdir -p "$JENKINS_HOME"/workspace/${job_name_2}

## Create the jobs folder recursively
RUN mkdir -p "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/${job_name_1}
RUN mkdir -p "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/${job_name_2}
RUN ls -ltr "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/

## Add the custom configs to the container
COPY configs/${job_name_1}/config.xml "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/${job_name_1}/config.xml
COPY configs/${job_name_2}/config.xml "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/${job_name_2}/config.xml

## Create build file structure
RUN mkdir -p "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/${job_name_1}/latest/
RUN mkdir -p "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/${job_name_1}/builds/1/

## Create build file structure
RUN mkdir -p "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/${job_name_2}/latest/
RUN mkdir -p "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/${job_name_2}/builds/1/

## Change ownership to jenkins user
RUN chown ${uid}:${gid} $JENKINS_HOME
```

Comment: Did you run `docker build` under folder `/opt/jenkins_config` on your local machine manually ?

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, `COPY configs/${job_name_1}/config.xml "$JENKINS_HOME"/jobs/${job_name_1}/config.xml` will be translated to next:

```
COPY /opt/jenkins_config/configs/Generate-Key/config.xml /var/jenkins_home/jobs/Generate-Key/config.xml
```

And as you said next:

> when I check the volume store on my host server (same location /var/jenkins_home/jobs).

So when `docker run` I guess you define a bind mount like next:

```
-v /var/jenkins_home/jobs:/var/jenkins_home/jobs
```

If above is same as your situation, then things clear:

When `docker build`, the `config.xml` already successfully copied to image with the location `/var/jenkins_home/jobs/Generate-Key/config.xml`, so you certainly got no error.

Issue happen when you do `docker run`, `-v /var/jenkins_home/jobs:/var/jenkins_home/jobs` will not pop the contents in container to host, it will just mount the folder on host to container, which means the host folder will override the same folder in container, so `config.xml` which was previously copied to image was override by empty host folder. So you see nothing, you can verify it without define `-v` & exec to container to have a check.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

So if I delete whatever's in `/var/jenkins_home` will that mean the container will not be overwritten when I do `docker run` ?

Comment: @T.Pope you mean delete things on host? Host folder will always override container folder . you can make experiment